# java: how to addAll(Collection<>) to the front of the queue?

Tags: java, collections, arraydeque

```
public void traverse(Node root){
    ArrayDeque<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<Node>();
        queue.add(root);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        Node currentNode = queue.pollFirst();   
        List<Node> nl = getChildrenfromDB(currentNode);
        queue.addAll(nl);
    }
```

how would I get `addAll(nl)` to add the entire collection(`List<Node>`) to the front of the queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing built-in. But it is simple to emulate - just iterate the list in reverse order and add the elements. That way they will end up in the queue in the right order.

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    queue.addFirst(node);
}
```

Other ways to iterate backwards are:

- `LinkedList`'s descending iterator
- `Collections.reverse(..)`

Pick one which fits your case.

Comment: isn't this slower than addAll() ?

Comment: yes but I want to retain the order of the Collection and simply place this entire Collection infront of other elements in the queue.

Comment: that's why you should iterate in reverse order, so that it ends up in the initial order

Answer (score 12):

Actually I was looking for the same thing, and this worked for me!!

```
samplelist.addAll(0,items); // 0 is the index where items are added on the list
```

Comment: This `addAll` variant is available in `java.util.AbstractList` but not in `java.util.ArrayDeque`.